# Web API 2 - are all REST requests asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

Do I need to do anything to make all requests asynchronous or are they automatically handled that way?

I ran some tests and it appears that each request comes in on its own thread, but I figure better to ask as I might have tested wrong.

**Update:** (I have a bad habit of not explaining fully - sorry) Here's my concern. A client browser makes a REST request to my server of http://data.domain/com/employee_database/?query=state:Colorado. That comes in to the appropriate method in the controller. That method queries the database and returns an object which is then turned into a JSON structure and returned to the calling app.

Now let's say 10,000 clients all make a similar query to the same server. So I have 10,000 requests coming in at once. Will my controller method be called simultaneously in 10,000 distinct threads? Or must the first request return before the second request is called?

I'm not asking about the code in my handler method having asynchronous components. For my case the request becomes a single SQL query so the code has nothing that can be handled asynchronously. And until I get the requested data, I can't return from the method.

Comment: If you mean async actions, than you should use `async`: `public async Task<IQueryable<string>> Get() { ... }`

Comment: @VladimirFrolov why can't the web api create a thread each time it starts serving the user? This way it wouldn't matter if one sleeps in the action as it would be in own thread already.

Comment: @David Could you please elaborate on your findings. Replies below doesn't seem to answer your specific question.

Comment: @EvolGate I think the marked answer does answer my question.

Comment: @DavidThielen Actually, I have a Web Api 2 project and it is working synchronously. I mean I tried hitting the GET URL from various browsers at the same time but the console logs are printed in serial order. If the requests are asynchronous then how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, your question is not very clear. If you are making an HTTP GET using `HttpClient`, say  the `GetAsync` method, request is fired and you can do whatever you want in your thread until the time you get the response back. So, this request is asynchronous. If you are asking about the server side, which handles this request (assuming it is ASP.NET Web API), then asynchronous or not is up to how you implemented your web API. If your action method, does three things, say 1, 2, and 3 one after the other synchronously in blocking mode, the same thread is going to the service the request. On the other hand, say #2 above is a call to a web service and it is an HTTP call. Now, if you use HttpClient and you make an asynchronous call, you can get into a situation where one request is serviced by more than one thread. For that to happen, you should have made the HTTP call from your action method asynchronously and used `async` keyword. In that case, when you call `await` inside the action method, your action method execution returns and the thread servicing your request is free to service some other request and ultimately when the response is available, the same or some other thread will continue from where it was left off previously. Long boring answer, perhaps but difficult to explain just through words by typing, I guess. Hope you get some clarity.

**UPDATE:**
Your action method will execute **in parallel** in 10,000 threads (ideally). Why I'm saying ideally is because a CLR thread pool having 10,000 threads is not typical and probably impractical as well. There are physical limits as well as limits imposed by the framework as well but I guess the answer to your question is that the requests will be serviced in parallel. The correct term here will be 'parallel' but not 'async'.

Comment: Sorry, I have a bad habit of assuming people can read my mind for the details. I updated the question and I hope it's now sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. My testing showed that but better to have an authoritative answer as my test could have been off. And I'm fine if for that example it's 1,000 parallel requests and the rest are queued up. The underlying database is going to hit it's parallel limits around then too I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2):

No REST is not async by default. the request are handled synchronously. However, your web server (IIS) has a number of max threads setting which can work at the same time, and it maintains a queue of the request received. So, the request goes in the queue and if a thread is available it gets executed else, the request waits in the IIS queue till a thread is available

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using async IO/operations such as database calls in your case. Yes in Web Api, every request has its own thread, but threads can run out if there are many consecutive requests. Also threads use memory so if your api gets hit by too many request it may put pressure on your system.

The benefit of using async over sync is that you use your system resources wisely. Instead of blocking the thread while it is waiting for the database call to complete in sync implementation, the async will free the thread to handle more requests or assign it what ever process needs a thread. Once IO (database) call completes, another thread will take it from there and continue with the implementation. Async will also make your api run faster if your IO operations take longer to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is sync or async is your choice. You choose by the way to write your action. If you return a Task, and also use async IO under the hood, it is async. In other cases it is synchronous.

Don't feel tempted to slap `async` on your action and use `Task.Run`. That is async-over-sync (a known anti-pattern). It must be truly async all the way down to the OS kernel.

No framework can make sync IO automatically async, so it cannot happen under the hood. Async IO is callback-based which is a severe change in programming model.

This does not answer what you *should* do of course. That would be a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think this answers my question. In the case of Web API I think the async has to occur in the Web API framework as I must return the data requested in the call. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is your question then? "Do I need to do anything to make all requests asynchronous or are they automatically handled that way?" => Yes, you need to be async in your own action. The framework is not automatically async. It *can* behave asynchronously if you are as well. It mirrors what you do.; "as I must return the data requested in the call": you can either return it synchronously (without async and without using Task). Then the action will be synchronous. You can also return a Task which will make the action asynchronous. With a Task, you do not need to return the result immediately.

Comment: "Will my controller method be called simultaneously in 10,000 distinct threads?":With a synchronous action, it will be called on many threads (not exactly 10k but many). With an async action the number of threads will be very low (near the amount of CPUs) but the number of concurrently active action will still be high (that limit can be configured). All async does is unblock request threads so you have fewer of them. It does not change (direcly) how many actions are being processed at the same time.;"Or must the first request return before the second request is called?":that is never the case.

Comment: "For my case the request becomes a single SQL query so the code has nothing that can be handled asynchronously" Async *can* be about doing stuff in parallel (e.g. two SQL queries at the same time). It can also be about unblocking threads while still doing only one thing at a time. IO does not need to use a thread because the OS kernel supports threadless IO. SQL queries are IO. In your case async is about unblocking threads.

Comment: I think you're not understanding my question. I have a Web API 2 server component. When a client requests a url that will return JSON data, the appropriate method in my controller is called. I have no control over what occurs up to that point. And I must return the requested data from that call. So there's nothing I can do asynchronously. The question is: does Web API 2 send in multiple requests in parallel, or does it queue them up and send them one at a time?

Comment: I probably do not understand your question because there is some terminology to clear up. We understand the word async differently as it seems. async does not mean parallel. It means callback-based, not stack based.; "I have no control over what occurs up to that point." You do: by the return type of your action you choose what the framework does before it calls you. Maybe you should search for what "webapi async" really means.; Web API does send multiple requests, as I said in the comments.; This was not a fruitful endeavor for both of us. Glad you got your answer anyway.

Comment: Sorry - I use async and Parallel interchangably - as does wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_programming